# emacs register in custom function

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm trying to add two keybinds in my dot emacs, to save / restore a buffer position.

So, here is my code:

```
(defun savePosition()
  (interactive)
  (point-to-register "m"))

(defun goToPosition()
  (interactive)
  (jump-to-register "m"))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-M") 'savePosition)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-m") 'goToPosition)
```

Unfortunatly it doesn't work. No error in emacs, but the register seems no exists - I think it's because the register is saved in function and not for current buffer.

So, how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Replace:

```
"m"
```

With:

```
?m
```

Comment: Indeed. Your original attempt doesn't work because `(eq "m" "m")` is `nil` (as the reader creates independent objects for the two strings). You probably don't want to use a character either, though. Interactively, registers are characters; but in code you can use anything comparable with `eq` so it is sensible to use a non-conflicting symbol for this purpose, so that you're not clobbering the interactive use of one of the register characters.